# C# Datagridview overlapping text without using OnPaint

Tags: c#, datagridview, merge, overlapping, cells

I need help to solve my problem with overlapping text in a DataGridView (winform). In every 7 row i need to write a summery text that overlapping at least 5 cells horizontally. I have solved it by painting a rectangle with a string when OnPaint occurs. The problem is that OnPaint is very slow and it is very slow to scroll around in the control.

I also have not find out any way to update the datagridview while scrolling???

Is there any way to to overlapping text without using OnPaint? like Excel when a "long" text in a cell automatically overlap the cell to the right if the cell to the right is empty??

I have try to google on merge cells, but i think datagridview does´t support that?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use this graphics setting while painting :

```
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```

Or Use

```
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```